# can not convert to a c\c++ project eclipse ndk cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

Hi, I'm new to android developing with NDK , I'm using `ndk-r9d` and `cocos2d-x 2.2.3`.
When I create a project with `cocos` and import to Eclipse , in the conversion phase the name of the project not shown in the candidate for conversion section of convert to a `C``C++` project.

Can anyone help me???

Comment: Are you sure the project doesn't already have a c++ nature? When you open the project properties - does it have "C++" menus?

Comment: this is what i did.create a project in cocos with cpp language , go to proj.android run build.native.sh . in eclipse create a new project from android project from existing code .when i want to convert to c\c++ project the name of project not shown in selection area.

Comment: by the way , yes it has c\c++ build section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might well be that the project is already with C/C++ nature,
you said you have the C++ menus,
do you also have for example this menu in the image?
If so, you're good to go and start compiling C++ code.

[image: C++ Support]

Comment: thanks for your help, but there is no such c\c++ index under the project menu

Comment: finally I find the solution , just need to add the libcocos2dx project to eclipse . it's in the following path. cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src

Comment: @soha1410 Do you have a link for a tutorial you followed because the cocos2dx tutorial on their official site is useless for me

Answer (score 0):

try using the eclipse c/c++ development. I was also facing same issue when using eclipse for java/jee development. I simply added C/C++ support by downloading packages to Java/Jee eclipse. After installing proper eclipse for c/C++ development, I was able to see "convert to c/C++...." option.